# extending existing model with new fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django project, where I use a third-party extension that inserts its own models (something like `ExtensionApp.Model1` and `ExtensionApp.Model2`).

I need to make some adjustments (specifically add a couple new fields there). Right now what I do is `OneToOne` field in my own app model to `ExtensionApp.Model1`, and there I can add what I need. I just don't want to touch the core of this extension app.

But I think whether it is the right way to do? Is there a way to add new fields to existing models of third-party app? I know there are proxy models (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) but these allow to add new methods, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit the models and add new fields.

[Model Inheritance Styles in Django](https://medium.com/@lokeshsharma596/model-inheritance-styles-in-django-698296f5de06)

[Model Inheritance in Python Django](https://medium.com/@DigitallyMani/model-inheritance-in-python-django-51438cacd9cc)

**Suggestion:**

You go with OnetoOne relationship instead of inheriting models.